# Golang Non Blocking os.Stdin Read for Cmd

Tags: go, stdin, nonblocking

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("env")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

This works well regardless `env` command doesn't relay on reading from `stdin`

Yet for

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("env")
reader, writer := os.Pipe()
go func() {
  io.Copy(writer, os.Stdin)
  reader.Close()
}()
cmd.Stdin = reader
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

It executes `env` command well but next blocks until whatever input is made (regardless  `env` doesn't need it)

Even such would reproduce the situation

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("env")
cmd.Stdin = struct{io.Reader}{os.Stdin}
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

But this actually reproduces the Pipe flow under the hood of Cmd implementation it self once the Stdin is not *os.File (see [code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=503)
)

```golang
    if f, ok := c.Stdin.(*os.File); ok {
        return f, nil
    }

    pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ...
```

So wat is the basic difference here as io.Copy [says](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) it should behave the very same way

```
Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs
```

So what is the diff on providing directly os.Stdin to piping it over intermediate Reader. And how to make a Pipe approach behave the same non blocking way

My actual case is even more complex as it pipes the stdin over a `net.Conn` still I hope the. understanding of described behavior would give me the same clue for the solution.

Thx.

Comment: When you use `os.Stdin` file descriptor is passed directly to the child process, and if `cmd.Stdin` is not a normal file, then the exec package needs to create a goroutine to pipe the data across for you similar to your `os.Pipe` example. The difference is that the command receives a tty it can check directly. If you redirected the parent go process stdin from a fifo you would also get the same blocking behavior.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. On a very high level I can see your idea. But could your clarify a little? Is it a matter of Cmd implementation or underling shell command it self? What is the reason for checking for tty once stdin seems not being needed for `env` at all? Why after command is closed not just to close stdin regardless it is tty or not?  Maybe is there a line In Cmd code to point me for a better understanding? thx

Comment: The behavior isn't directly related to Go or the exec package, most non-interactive programs that can accept data via stdin will check if there is anything to read by inspecting what their stdin is. If you want to accept data via stdin, and it's a pipe, you must read until you get the data you expect or the pipe is closed. Run `env < fifo` in the shell and it will also block.